How to get cleveref to properly use custom highlighting for subsubsections in the appendix?
For a document, I needed multiple custom citation commands with highlighting and links. As a basis, the cleveref package was used. The following MWE shows the implementation principle (only a few select commands, some of which might seem redundant due to similar functionality already provided by the cleveref package, but are only a substitute for much more complex macros which cannot be shown in a MWE due to their complexity).
MWE
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{fontawesome5} % REMARK: Required for arrow symbol 

% DESCRIPTION: Number also subsubsections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

% DESCRIPTION: General highlight macro
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{#1}}}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% DESCRIPTION: Setup of cleveref
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[nosort]{cleveref}

% DESCRIPTION: Set citation styles properly
\creflabelformat{chapter}{#2\highlight{#1}#3}
\creflabelformat{section}{#2\highlight{#1}#3}
\creflabelformat{subsection}{#2\highlight{#1}#3}
\creflabelformat{subsubsection}{#2\highlight{#1}#3} % Not properly working

\creflabelformat{appendix}{#2\highlight{#1}#3}

% DESCRIPTION: Make template macro
\newcommand{\referenceStyleTEMPLATE}[1]{%
    \raisebox{0.125em}{%
        \tiny\color{orange}\faLongArrowAltRight%
    }\highlight{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\referenceTEMPLATE}[2][]{%
    \hyperref[#2]{%
        \referenceStyleTEMPLATE{#1}\labelcref{#2}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\referenceSection}[1]{%
    \referenceTEMPLATE[\,Section~]{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\referenceAppendix}[1]{%
    \referenceTEMPLATE[\,Appendix~]{#1}%
}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter in the Main Document}
        \label{main::chapter}
        \section{Section in the Main Document}
            \label{main::section}
            \subsection{Subsection in the Main Document}
                \label{main::subsection}
                \subsubsection{Subsubsection in the Main Document}
                    \label{main::subsubsection}
                        Test Chapter (Main): \referenceSection{main::chapter}.\\ 
                        Test Section (Main): \referenceSection{main::section}.\\ 
                        Test Subsection (Main): \referenceSection{main::subsection}.\\
                        Test Subsubsection (Main): \referenceSection{main::subsubsection}.\\
                        Test Chapter (Appendix): \referenceSection{appendix::chapter}.\\ 
                        Test Section (Appendix): \referenceSection{appendix::section}.\\ 
                        Test Subsection (Appendix): \referenceSection{appendix::subsection}.\\
                        Test Subsubsection (Appendix): \referenceSection{appendix::subsubsection}.
                
    \appendix
    {\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Chapter in the Appendix}} % REMARK: Just to get everything onto one page for demonstration purposes
        \label{appendix::chapter}
        \section{Section in the Appendix}
            \label{appendix::section}
            \subsection{Subsection in the Appendix}
                \label{appendix::subsection}
                \subsubsection{Subsubsection in the Appendix}
                    \label{appendix::subsubsection}
                    Test Chapter (Main): \referenceSection{main::chapter}.\\ 
                    Test Section (Main): \referenceSection{main::section}.\\ 
                    Test Subsection (Main): \referenceSection{main::subsection}.\\
                    Test Subsubsection (Main): \referenceSection{main::subsubsection}.\\
                    Test Chapter (Appendix): \referenceSection{appendix::chapter}.\\ 
                    Test Section (Appendix): \referenceSection{appendix::section}.\\ 
                    Test Subsection (Appendix): \referenceSection{appendix::subsection}.\\
                    Test Subsubsection (Appendix): \referenceSection{appendix::subsubsection}.
\end{document}

The produced output is the following:


Everything works fine except for subsubsections in the appendix: There, the cleveref package does not apply the correct highlighting.
Questions

Did I miss some setting for the cleveref package?
Is there a (simple) workaround available?

